# Liferay7.0 portlet build with angular and typescript

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, liferay, portlet

I'm wondering, is it possible to create a liferay7.0 portlet based on angular(2, angular material v1.1.1) and typescripting.

I know its possible to load (for example) Angular 1.4 lib and create a portlet with plain javascript/angular code
source: https://web.liferay.com/web/sampsa.sohlman/blog/-/blogs/trying-the-angularjs-with-liferay

What i would like to achieve is to create a portlet based on nodejs packages. and to compile it with gulp or something to a war file.

Comment: I don't see a question here. _Is it possible?_ Many things are possible. Such kind of questions are to broad to be answered on Stackoverflow. What about to try it and come back, if you have a more specific question. Or you start a discussion in the Liferay-Forum, which will be more helpful for such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Open for discussion.
Possible ways i can see, irrespective of Angular 2 & More focused on Single Page Application In General

1. Liferay 7 Provides ES6 Support. Your write your ES6 code & Then transpile it & install it as a module. Gradle in Liferay IDE has a option for transpilation & import is a seperate package, which can be used through out all modules in the OSGI Container.
2. Liferay 7 Introduced Metal JS. Metal JS has template support for SOY & JSX. Again it has same process, write ES6 Code, transpile it , install the module & Use it.
3. When explored liferay source code it uses babel & not typescript. there are files with extension .es.js. & Liferay uses AMD Module loader, so there needs to be a task for typescript & AMD Loader, which then can be passed. Such task needs to be created & Then loading the module can be done by something like this

   require('my-dialog', function(myDialog) {
       // your code here
   }, function(error) {
       console.error(error);
   });

Reference :- https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/liferay-amd-module-loader

4. Liferay introduced senna JS. Again its es6 transpiled file, where corresponding to each route we define a page, In that page we can keep a component to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively you can integrate Liferay with Angular. Currently exists an official and functional example in:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/gradle/apps/npm/angular-npm-portlet

But my personal recommendation is don't merge in the same page an Angular portlet with an not Angular portlet.

Answer (score -1):

Integrating java based portals with angular is very complicated. Liferay is shipped with `AlloyUi`. There are side effects for using multiple JS libraries together such as `AlloyUI` with Angularjs.
Side effects usually manifests themselves in higher load times and possible conflicts. A single angular app protlet is required for every page containing an angular portlet. Once two instances of the same angular portlet are dropped on a page, this will lead to a conflict unless everything is namespaced (`<div ng-app="myapp"> ==> <div id="myapp<portlet:namespace/>">`).
It is not possible to define URLs in advance as in classic application development with angularjs. Liferay portal uses its own System-generated URLs so generated tags are needed(`portlet:defineObjects, portlet:resourceURL ...`) to create:

```
 <URLs(portlet:resourceURL id="config" 
var="config">/portlet:resourceURL> 
<script> var urlConfig = '${config}'; </script>)
```

and these tags will not be available in javascript file since the javascript loads first. 
This end up complicating development with angularjs and URLs handling issues are frequently encountered. A lot of workaround code is required to integrate portal URLs into angular since angular also controls URLS. And this is basically a try to integrate two directly competing technologies.
A compromise between AlloyUI and Angular must be developed, which will cause more dilemma than provide any actual benefit.
To be short, technological agnosticism sounds great in theory, but it practically does not work that well and it has more complications and disadvantages than actual benefits.
If you believe that developing then integrating a standalone web application into a portal can solve the problem, then this should be looked again because login credentials cannot be shared with the embedded application. In this case liferay has no utility.

Comment: You load AlloyUI and other libraries in your theme only if you want.

Comment: Javascript do not load first than Liferay URL's. Every jsp taglib is rendered first in the server. When javascript is loading, all JSP variables are resolved.